# Create designer.cs file from ResXRersourcewriter generated resource file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resx

I got a programm that generates `.resx` resource files. Those resource files are used in other projects, that isnt in the same solution as the project that generates the resource files.

I wonder now, if its possible to generate a `designer.cs` file from the resource file, so that you can access the resources directly without using the resxresourcereader.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Open the resx file and on its toolbar there's an `Access Modifier` menu. Set this to `Public`. This will generate a `*.Designer.cs` file.

[image]

Comment: The project file / TFS sometimes gets confused when people rename the resx. Just delete the .cs file and recreating it using this works like a charm.

Comment: Setting Access Modifier to Public worked flawlessly - thanks.

Comment: Saving the Resources.resx is enough, no need to change Access modifier.

Comment: In VS 2017 set property "Custom Tool" to value "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator"

Answer (score 13):

Right click on the `Resources.resx` and select "Run Custom Tool".

Comment: Right click the resx-file and select properties. Add the value "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" to the "Custom Tool" property then the designer file will be generated.

Comment: Is there a way to do that in the build process itself?

Answer (score 8):

If the file is added to a Visual Studio Project you have to set the `Custom Tool` property of the `.resx` file to `ResXFileCodeGenerator`. Then will VS automatically create the needed designer file.

In one project I made a T4 script that scans the folder within the project for all images and let create a corresponding ressource file at a click.

Here is the needed part out of the T4 script:

```
var rootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(this.Host.TemplateFile);

var imagesPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Images");
var resourcesPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, "Resources");

var pictures = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath, "*.png", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)((IServiceProvider)this.Host)
                   .GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

EnvDTE.Projects projects = dte.Solution.Projects;
EnvDTE.Project iconProject = projects.Cast<EnvDTE.Project>().Where(p => p.Name == "Icons").Single();
EnvDTE.ProjectItem resourcesFolder = iconProject.ProjectItems.Cast<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>().Where(item => item.Name == "Resources").Single();

// Delete all existing resource files to avoid any conflicts.
foreach (var item in resourcesFolder.ProjectItems.Cast<EnvDTE.ProjectItem>())
{
    item.Delete();
}

// Create the needed .resx file fore each picture.
foreach (var picture in pictures)
{
    var resourceFilename =  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(picture) + ".resx";
    var resourceFilePath = Path.Combine(resourcesPath, resourceFilename);

    using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(resourceFilePath))
    {
        foreach (var picture in picturesByBitmapCollection)
        {
            writer.AddResource(picture.PictureName, new ResXFileRef(picture, typeof(Bitmap).AssemblyQualifiedName));
        }
    }
}

// Add the .resx file to the project and set the CustomTool property.
foreach (var resourceFile in Directory.GetFiles(resourcesPath, "*.resx"))
{
    var createdItem = resourcesFolder.Collection.AddFromFile(resourceFile);
    var allProperties = createdItem.Properties.Cast<EnvDTE.Property>().ToList();
    createdItem.Properties.Item("CustomTool").Value = "ResXFileCodeGenerator";
}
```

I have flattened the above code a little bit, cause in my real solution i use a custom class for each picture instead of the simple filename to also support the same filename in different sub folders (by using a part of the folder structure for the namespace generation). But for a first shot the above should help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this in code:
(Taken from here: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true))

```
 StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@".\DemoResources.cs");
  string[] errors = null;
  CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
  CodeCompileUnit code = StronglyTypedResourceBuilder.Create("Demo.resx", "DemoResources", 
                                                             "DemoApp", provider, 
                                                             false, out errors);    
  if (errors.Length > 0)
     foreach (var error in errors)
        Console.WriteLine(error); 

  provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(code, sw, new CodeGeneratorOptions());                                         
  sw.Close();
```

You need to reference system.design.dll

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me: double click and open the resx file, add a dummy resource, click save. the .designer.cs file is generated.

Comment: Saving the `Resources.resx` is enough, no need for the dummy resource.

Answer (score 0):

If you deleted it or added it to .gitignore because you thought you didn't need it. this is how you regenerate the file.

Go to the Access modifier and change it from (Public/Internal) to "No Code Generation"

Now put it back to Public/Internal.
VS will regenerate the Designer file for you.

Comment: Saving the `Resources.resx` is enough, no need to change `Access modifier`.